# How to start ggplot2 geom_bar from different origin

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to start a bar chart at somewhere other than the y = 0.  In my case, I want to start the bar chart at y = 1.

As an example, let's say that I build a identity `geom_bar()` chart with ggplot2.

```
df <- data.frame(values = c(1, 2, 0),
                 labels = c("A", "B", "C"))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = values, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Now, I'm not asking how to set scale or axis limits.  I want bars representing values less than 1 to flow down from y = 1.

It needs to look like this...but with a different y axis:

[image]

Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just change the labels manually, as shown in the other answer. However, I think conceptually the better solution is to define a transformation object that transforms the y axis scale as requested. With that approach, you're literally just modifying the relative baseline for the bar plots, and you can still set breaks and limits as you normally would.

```
df <- data.frame(values = c(1,2,0), labels = c("A", "B", "C"))

t_shift <- scales::trans_new("shift",
                             transform = function(x) {x-1},
                             inverse = function(x) {x+1})

ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = values, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = t_shift)
```

[image]

Setting breaks and limits:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = values, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = t_shift,
                     limits = c(-0.5, 2.5),
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = labels, y = values-1, fill = labels, colour = labels)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'values', 
                     breaks = seq(-1, 1, 0.5), 
                     labels = seq(-1, 1, 0.5) + 1)
```

[image]