# Diverging bar plot (with y-hline different from 0) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´d made a `Y-maze` experiment, where values goes to 0 (total preference to stimulus  **A**) to 1 (total preference to stimulus **B**), index response is calculated as : `# flies on stimulus B/(# flies stimulus A+B)`

**A** 0.5 value means no differential election (a 50-50 random distribution) 
I need to make a diverging plot with means very similar to this with `ggplot2`:

[image]

NOTE: y-values starts from 0.5, what i want to make is the horizontal line in y=0.5, and that the bars starts from 0.5

here´s some of my data:

```
data<-data.frame(Line= c(21,181,208,217), mean= c(0.584, 0.897, 0.345, 0.67)
data$Linea<-as.factor(data$Line)
```

What I have tried is this code:

```
data$category<- ifelse(data$mean >0.5, "grape","apple")

ggplot(data,aes(x = Line ,y =mean)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = category),stat = "identity") +
  labs(title= "Diverging Bars")+
  ylim(0,1)+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5)
```

and what I had is this:
[image]

Comment: Would you provide some data with `dput` and code you have tried?

Comment: Possibly what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48794575/how-to-start-ggplot2-geom-bar-from-different-origin