# colour geom_rect under certain condition

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I´ve got the following code:

```
ggplot(dummy$Crustacean) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = char2num(sites_fct) - 0.4,
      xmax = char2num(sites_fct) + 0.4,
      ymin = ifelse(trophic == "Crustacean", 0.01, 1),
      ymax = summed_tu),
    colour = 'black', alpha =0.7) +
  labs(y= expression("Summed TU"[EC10-QSAR]), x= "Sampling sites")+
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(0.0001, 1)) +
  # Fake discrete axis
  scale_x_continuous(labels = sort(unique(dummy$Crustacean$sites_fct)), breaks = 1:9) +
  # before the dot means vertical plotting
  facet_grid(dummy$Crustacean$metrics_fct ~ dummy$Crustacean$trophic) +
  theme_bw()+
  # facet_grid box colour
  theme(strip.background.x = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = "white"),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_blank())+
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, margin =margin(0,0,0,0), angle =45, vjust = 1, hjust=1),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y  = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x  = element_line(color = 'black', size=0.5),
        axis.line.y  = element_blank())
```

which give as uutput the following figure:

[image]

I need to change the colour of those boxes y > 0.01 in order to have this desire output:

[image]

I found several post about background (quite useful for the future) but I cloud not find something like my example.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please paste your data into the question as an object using `dput(dummy$Crustacean)` so that solutions can be tested and verified?

Comment: OP - Looks like you're trying to make a column/bar chart.  It will probably be way easier to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_rect`.  You only have to supply a discrete x aesthetic and a y aesthetic.

Comment: @Peter it has more than 2000 characters... I cannot copy as comment

Comment: @chemdork123 You are right, but the full figure is more complex and when I used `geom_col` I dont get what I exactly need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP, this should probably help you.  You're trying to draw what appears to be a column or bar chart.  In this case, it's probably best to use `geom_col` instead of `geom_rect`.  With `geom_col` you only have to supply an `x` aesthetic (discrete value), and a `y` aesthetic for the height of the bar.  You have not shared your data, but it seems the x axis is categorical already in your dataset, right?

Here's a reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=LETTERS, y=rnorm(26))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_col(
    aes(fill=ifelse(y>0, 'positive', 'negative')),
    color='black', alpha=0.8
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='Value', values=c('positive'='orange', 'negative'='gray'))
```

[image]

What's going on here is that we only have to supply `x` and `y` to get the bars in the correct place and set the height.  For the `fill` of each of the bars, you can actually just set the label to be "positive" or "negative" (or whatever your desired label would be) on the fly via an `ifelse` statement.  Doing this alone will result in creating a legend automatically with fill colors chosen automatically.  To fix a particular set of colors, I'm setting that manually via `scale_fill_manual()` and supplying a named vector to the `values` argument.

In your case, you can probably do something similar for `geom_rect`.  That is, you could just try specifying `fill=` inside `aes()` and following a similar manner to here if you want... but I'd recommend switching to use `geom_col`, as it is most appropriate for what you're doing.

#### EDIT

As OP indicated in the comment, in the [original question on which this is based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387471/manipulate-scale-y-log-in-geom-bar-ggplot2%5D), `geom_rect` is required since the bars minimum is not always the same number.  The `ymin` aesthetic changes, so it makes sense to use `geom_rect` here.

The brute force way is to still use `ifelse` statements inside `aes()` for `fill`.  It get's a bit dodgey, but it gets the job done:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = char2num(sites) - 0.4,
      xmax = char2num(sites) + 0.4,
      ymin = ifelse(trop == "pt", 0.1, 1),
      ymax = conc,
      fill = ifelse(trop == "pt",
                ifelse(conc > 0.1, 'positive', 'negative'),
                ifelse(conc > 1, 'positive', 'negative'))
    ),
    colour = 'black', alpha = 0.8
  ) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  # Fake discrete axis
  scale_x_continuous(labels = sort(unique(df$sites)),
                     breaks = 1:3) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='Conc', values=c('positive'='orange', 'negative'='gray')) +
  facet_grid(. ~ trop) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

To complete the setup, you may want to adjust the order of the items in the legend and avoid some of that kind of icky nested `ifelse` stuff.  In that case, you can always do the checking outside the `ggplot` call.  If you have more than the two values for `df$trop`, you can consider creating the `df$conc_min` column via a merge with another dataset, but it works just fine here.

```
df$conc_adjust <- char2num(df$sites)
df$conc_min <- ifelse(df$trop=='pt', 0.1, 1)
df$status <- ifelse(df$conc > df$conc_min, 'positive', 'negative')

# levels of the factor = the order appearing in the legend
df$status <- factor(df$status, levels=c('positive', 'negative'))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = conc_adjust - 0.4,
      xmax = conc_adjust + 0.4,
      ymin = conc_min,
      ymax = conc,
      fill = status
    ),
    colour = 'black', alpha = 0.8
  ) +
  scale_y_log10() +
  # Fake discrete axis
  scale_x_continuous(labels = sort(unique(df$sites)),
                     breaks = 1:3) +
  scale_fill_manual(name='Conc', values=c('positive'='orange', 'negative'='gray')) +
  facet_grid(. ~ trop) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Here is the reason why I do not use `geom_col` [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66387471/manipulate-scale-y-log-in-geom-bar-ggplot2] This is the full figure (https://ibb.co/2MXpMpw)

Comment: you can realise that it has different log breaks in the y-axis, they dont start at 0

Comment: OK - @PedrNton, I've made an edit based on your original question and which uses `geom_rect`.  You have some options there.

Comment: Excellent! extremely useful. Thanks for your help. @chemdork123

Comment: Of course.  Like I mention in the answer, if your actual case has many facets (different `df$trop` values), I would suggest making a separate data frame that includes a `trop` column and a `conc_min` column, then doing a `left_join()` or another merge with your `df` dataset by the `trop` column to map the `conc_min` column... .better than a billion nested `ifelse()` statements!